# How to properly get Account Id to frontend from Stripe Connect?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have and app that uses connected accounts with Stripe. I need to store information about which Stripe account is linked to the specific client in my app. So my current workflow is:

1. I set a **Stripe Account Id** to the client of my app in Database
2. On the specific page, my Frontend sends request about which Account Id is linked to the specific client
3. I send a Stripe Account Id as a response to my Frontend
4. I process Card information with the connected account on my Frontend and send the **Token** to my Backend
5. On the backend, I create Source and retrieve it back to Frontend
6. On the Frontend, I handle the possible 3DS and send a Source back to my Backend
7. On the backend, I finish the payment and send status back to my Frontend

So, my question is - Is there any possible security risk during the process? I could not figure out any other way of passing Account Id information to the frontend. I need to initialize Stripe on Frontend with a specific Account Id to check Credit card data via Stripe Elements. Without the Account Id in my Frontend, I cannot create Card payment linked to the specific connected Stripe Account, so I think, there is no other way - Am I wrong?

As clients in my application changes, there is no possibility to store an Account Ids in an ENV file, I just have to get it from my server somehow.

I also tried to check Card info via Stripe elements using just PK stored in my ENV file, but then, when I wanted to finish payment with a connected Account, the process failed.

Do you guys have any secure workflow for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing account and source (did you mean PaymentMethod?) IDs with your frontend is not just fine, it's expected. In order to make requests with Stripe.js on behalf of connected accounts you need to [provide](https://stripe.com/docs/js/initializing#init_stripe_js-options-stripeAccount) the account ID when initializing.

Doing anything malicious with those IDs requires a secret key, which as long as you aren't sharing that with the client you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant Source - that I am using for checking if 3DS is required and handling it accordingly. Just if anyone is curious, I finally dealed with Account ID using SSR - I am fetching Account ID on the server so it is not exposed in Network traffic on client side. So if you guys are using a SSR framework, you can add additional layer of security. Of course, also secret ID is securely stored on my server in an ENV file. Thanks for clarification.